# Understanding the significance of @ProcessApplication

Tags: camunda

I see the following way to create Camunda Process applications :

```
@ProcessApplication
public class SpringServletProcessApplication extends ServletProcessApplication {
  ...
}
```

I what scenarios, do we use the above method ? When the project is not a springboot project ?

But when working with spring boot application, we don't need the annotation @ProcessApplication, why so ? Does SpringBoot Application contains own process application ?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebappExampleProcessApplication {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebappExampleProcessApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can see what the annotation does here:
https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter/blob/master/starter/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/spring/boot/starter/annotation/EnableProcessApplication.java

> Annotation that disables the {@link SpringProcessEngineConfiguration}  * auto-deploy feature and instead
> uses the required META-INF/processes.xml
> as an indicator for
> resource scanning. This also allows all processes.xml
> configuration features described here:
>  href="https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-applications/the-processes-xml-deployment-descriptor/">The
> processes.xml Deployment Descriptor

So you don't need the annotation if you are happy with the standard auto-deployment for process and decision models and have no need to override the default location of the process.xml file.

You may also find this class (or the other code in the project) interesting, in case you want to understand all the tings the Camunda Spring Boot Starter does: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter/blob/master/starter/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/spring/boot/starter/SpringBootProcessApplication.java#L99